# Comparing values from a javascript array and make sure each value is at least 10 apart

Tags: javascript

There is the following array which contains sub-array's (each sub-array being a pair of coordinates on a HTML5 canvas):

```
var myArray = [[364, 124], 
               [192, 272], 
               [209, 217], 
               [332, 227], 
               [241, 273], 
               [356, 387], 
               [104, 185], 
               [361, 380], 
               [297, 390], 
               [371, 311], 
               [191, 293]];
```

How can I compare each pair of coordinates and make sure each values is at least 10 apart.

For example:
Compare the number 272 (from the array indexed 1) to the number 273 (from the array indexed 4) - since there are only 1 apart, add 10 to one value.

Here is what I have tried:

Here I randomly generate the numbers, but I can relate to just the last generated pair.

```
function crosses(){
    var crossx, crossy, oldCrossx, oldCrossy, col;
    for(var i=0; i<=10; i++){

    crossx = randomFromInterval(100, xw-100);
    crossy = randomFromInterval(100, xh-100);


    if(crossesPos.length > 0){
        oldCrossx = crossesPos[i-1][0];
        oldCrossy = crossesPos[i-1][1];
        if(crossx - oldCrossx < 20){
            crossx += 10;
        }
        if(crossx - oldCrossx < -20 ){
            crossx -= 10;
        }
        if(crossy - oldCrossy < 20){
            crossy += 10;
        }
        if(crossy - oldCrossy < -20 ){
            crossy -= 10;
        }
    }
}
```

So I was thinking of a new approach, and alter the data after all the numbers were generated and already in an array.

I am thinking that I am taking the wrong approach:

Maybe I need a better way to generate numbers - right now I am using this function to generate numbers between certain intervals.

```
function randomFromInterval(from,to){
        return Math.floor(Math.random()*(to-from+1)+from);
    }
```

Comment: Of course, one second to edit the question

Comment: Iterate. Compare. If difference not > 10, modify. Copy correct[ed] values to new array or replace value in original.

Comment: How many times does this check need to occur? It could go on for a very long time depending on the size of `myArray`. Is there a maximum number for each of the x and y pairs? Are you sure you're getting to the end you want by the proper means?

Comment: myArray will have just 10 sub array-s. The code I wrote checks each last generated pair and compares it with the previous one. But I have realized it's not good because the numbers are randomly generated.

Comment: So I am thinking to sort myArray after it has been generated and try an idea similar to what Dave Newton suggested

Comment: I just thought, maybe I should check each randomly generated number against each existing number in the whole myArray and modify it before actually inserting it into myArray

Comment: I believe the answer is in how I generate the numbers - I will post my number generating function

Comment: 10 (presumably pixels) in both the X and Y direction? Because that will put them at a minimum sqrt(200) (about 14) pixels apart.

Comment: I am working on another method to generate the numbers, and try to generate them properly, before they reach myArray - and I'll post the answer for future references. I thought it all wrong from the beginning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/GzFa4/)

```
var myArray = [
    [364, 124],
    [192, 272],
    [209, 217],
    [332, 227],
    [241, 273],
    [356, 387],
    [104, 185],
    [361, 380],
    [297, 390],
    [371, 311],
    [191, 293]
];

function distTen(element, index, array) {
    for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        if (Math.abs(element[0] - array[x][0]) < 10) array[x][0] += 10;
        if (Math.abs(element[1] - array[x][1]) < 10) array[x][1] += 10;
    }
}

function logIt(element, index, array) {
    console.log("a[" + index + "] = " + element);
}
myArray.forEach(distTen);
myArray.forEach(logIt);
```

**RESULTS**

```
a[0] = 394,134
a[1] = 202,302
a[2] = 229,227
a[3] = 342,247
a[4] = 251,303
a[5] = 376,407
a[6] = 114,195
a[7] = 381,390
a[8] = 307,410
a[9] = 401,321
a[10] = 191,293
```

Comment: Please note... there are **11** elements in the outer array, not 10. This is not what the OP said would be the case and is why the last set of numbers are incorrect. Remove the last set of coordinates and this will work perfectly.